# Evaluating $\sin(\pi+\epsilon)$

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

Is there a way to numerically evaluate $\sin x$ to arbitrary precision, with $x$ very close to $\pi$, in an efficient way, such as with quadratic convergence ?

Of course, you are not allowed to use the value of $\pi$, and the Taylor series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$ is considered inefficient. (It has only linear convergence).

Comment: Could you not just use a linearization? As I recall, $\sin x$ is essentially linear at its roots.

Comment: @superckl: no, that requires the knowledge of $\pi$. (If it was that easy, I woudn't be asking. And I ruled out Taylor.)

Comment: What about using a rapidly-convering sequence for $\pi$ to estimate $\epsilon$ with high accuracy?

Comment: A linearlization would not use the value of $\pi$ as your question states. It simply requires that you know $\sin x$ has slope $-1$ at $x=\pi$. Is your question meant to say with absolutely no knowledge of $\pi$?

Comment: @anomaly: you are working aroung the rules. $\pi$ unknown.

Comment: @superckl: can you show that linearization formula ? Presumably $ax+b$. What are $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust near $x=\pi$, we have $\sin x\approx -(x -\pi)$. I see now where the knowledge of $\pi$ comes in, my mistake.

Comment: I don't understand the rule that you're "not allowed to use the value of $\pi$." Surely you're allowed to evaluate series that rapidly converge to $\pi$? Otherwise I have no idea how to differentiate between series that are "allowed" and those that are "not allowed."

Comment: @YvesDaoust How precise are you wanting to be? Perhaps applying an addition formula and then a linearization? We have $\sin(x+\epsilon)=\sin(\pi)\cos(\epsilon)+\cos(\pi)\sin(\epsilon)$. This gives $\sin(\pi+\epsilon)=-\sin(\epsilon)$ You can then use the linearization $\sin(x)\approx x$ so that $\sin(\pi+\epsilon)\approx -\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't understand your objection to the Taylor series. For $\varepsilon = 0.01$, only three terms of the Taylor series yield better than machine precision.

Comment: Is rapid convergence the right way of thinking about evaluation of $\sin$? I use a Chebyshev transform which requires about 5 terms to evaluate $\sin$ anywhere on a bounded domain to double precision. Is 5 terms "linear", "quadratic", or "constant time"?

Comment: @MarkMcClure: I am in the context of big numbers, and $\epsilon$ is not available.

Comment: @user14717:  I am in the context of big numbers, this is why I am thinking in terms of convergence.

Comment: Do you have an application in mind?  That might help explain the restrictions (which seem strange taken by themselves).

Comment: If $x=\pi+\varepsilon$ is close to $\pi$, then it seems that you are in the context of small numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use $\sin(\pi+\epsilon)=-\sin(\epsilon)$. You can use now the Taylor series with $\epsilon$ instead of $\pi+\epsilon$, which is very efficient and does not use $\pi$:

$$ \sin(\pi+\epsilon)=-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\epsilon^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Comment: I do not understand how this will work without violating the constraints imposed by the OP. You need to compute $\epsilon = x - \pi$  in order to compute your right hand side. Sadly, we are not allowed to use the value of $\pi$.

Comment: The Taylor series also has linear convergence for $\epsilon$. (And $\epsilon$ is not available otherwise I wouldn't be asking.)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @user14717 we can express the sine function using Chebyshev polynomials. Specifically, we have
$$ \sin(z x) = 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty J_{2k+1}(z) T_{2k+1}(x) $$
where the $J_m$ are Bessel functions of the first kind and the $T_m$ are Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.

This is equation (5.17) from Chapter 5 of "Chebyshev polynomials" by 
Manson and Handscomb, CRC Press, 2003. A copy is available here.

http://dl.iranidata.com/book/daneshgahi/Chebyshev%20polynomials(www.iranidata.com).pdf

The flexibility afforded by having both $z$ and $x$ allows you to keep $x \in [-1,1]$ where the $T_n = \cos(n \cos^{-1} x)$ is nicely bounded. Moveover, since
$$ J_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k! \Gamma(k+n+1)} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2k+n}$$
it seems to me, that here there is a good chance for rapid convergence.

---

I have no objection to artificial constraints, such as  "you may not use the value of $\pi$" or "the convergence must be superlinear". "Elementary" solutions of difficult problems are useful pedagogical tools. They allow you to demonstate to your students that they have actually learned someting difficult. However, I object to is artificial restraints without motivation. Several users have asked you to explain your restraints. You have offered no explanation as far as I know.

This significantly reduces my interest in the problem.

In particular, I can not afford the time necessary to properly investigate the convergence of the Chebyshev series and program a routine which does the summation carefully.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am no more allowed to delete my question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Your question is fine. It is your motivation which I must understand and accept before I can afford to spend more time searching for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the identity $\text{sin}(x) = -\text{sin}(x - \pi)$. The condition number of the function $\text{sin}$ is
$$\text{cond}(\text{sin}, x) = \frac{x}{\text{tan}(x)}$$

For $x\approx \pi$, $x - \pi \approx 0$ and $\text{cond}(\text{sin}, x-\pi)\approx 1$. Suppose that $\text{sin}(x)$ is computed with relative accuracy $\delta_{\sin}\varepsilon$ for $x\approx 0$ and $\hat{y} = \text{fl}(x-\pi)$ is computed with relative accuracy $\delta_y\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is the machine precision. Then
$$\left|\frac{\text{fl}(-\text{sin}(\hat{y})) - \text{sin}(x)}{\text{sin}(x)}\right| \leq \left(\delta_{\sin} + \text{cond}(\text{sin}, x-\pi)\times\delta_y\right)\varepsilon + O(\varepsilon^2) \approx \left(\delta_{\sin} + \delta_y\right)\varepsilon$$

The standard way of computing $x-\pi$ gives very high $\delta_y$. However we can easily obtain $\delta_y = 1/2$ using for example compensated summation method.

Therefore we only need a fast and accurate method of computing $\text{sin}(x)$ for $x\approx 0$.

Comment: $x-\pi$ is not available.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why do you want to compute this function efficiently and accurately and in the same time impose artificial constraints? Value of $\pi$ can be easily computed with arbitrary precision. Why it is not good enough to reduce your problem to the problem of computing $sin(x)$ for $x\approx 0$  and computing $\pi$?

Comment: Because I want to use this to evaluate $\pi$ in a new way so computing $\pi$ by known methods is of no interest.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I entirely missed this your last comment. I encourage you to elaborate on this when you edit your question. Different algorithms for computing constants have value when one is testing new hardware.